# Failure in create.js file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I had made a create file in view in Ruby on Rails but when I am trying to create it is showing following error:

```
Rendered issue_tracker_accesses/_form.html.erb (21.0ms)
Rendered issue_tracker_accesses/create.js.erb (24.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 46ms (Views: 33.1ms | ActiveRecord: 2.6ms)
```

Controller Code:

```
def create
@issue_tracker_access = IssueTrackerAccess.new(issue_tracker_access_params)
@issue_tracker_accesses = IssueTrackerAccess.all
respond_to do |format|
  if @issue_tracker_access.save
     @issue_tracker_access = IssueTrackerAccess.new
    format.js { @flag = true }
  else
    flash.now[:alert] = 'Access Already Exist.'
    format.js { @flag = false }
  end
end
end
```

Comment: Can you write some more details, like what you are trying to achieve & what error u r facing

Comment: Its a type of form when i fill all the fields and click on create . It's not creating anything and showing an above error , and no data is going in database .

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the create method in the controller 
 write the creation logic in the controller & then render the create.js.erb with the fields or data which you want to display. 
Also, you need to set remote:true in your form.
 
Follow the steps writen in the example http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#a-simple-example

Comment: I had written in controller and and remote:true in form . But still error is coming .

Comment: Is it saving anything, what is the code of your js.erb, write some more logs'